# How to retrieve tables in a database ordered by tables with primary key constraints first and then the tables with foreign key constraints

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am running the query below on SQL Server to retrieve a list of tables from a database. While the query lists the tables, I am running a pipeline which writes to the tables but fails on some tables as it tries to write to the foreign key tables without filling the primary key constraint tables first. This is a trunc/load operation. How can I modify the query so that it orders the tables by the tables with the primary key constraints first, and then the tables with the foreign key constraints after.

```
SELECT '[' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '].[' + TABLE_NAME + ']' AS MyTableWithSchema
    ,TABLE_SCHEMA AS MySchema
    ,TABLE_NAME AS MyTable
FROM qlm.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
    AND TABLE_NAME != 'sysdiagrams'
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME ASC
```

I tried the query above but again this does not work for my use case.

Comment: The Information schema tables should NOT be used for this. The schema values are not always updated. This is very clear in the documentation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/tables-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16 You should use sys.objects as the only reliable way to find a schema of an object.

Comment: Thank you  so much for the reference Sean, I will review the documentation and implement this as instructed to follow best practice. I really appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  can add more types to the order case, to sort other Constraint_Type

```
SELECT 
'[' + tab.TABLE_SCHEMA + '].[' + tab.TABLE_NAME + ']' AS MyTableWithSchema
   ,tab.TABLE_SCHEMA AS MySchema
    ,tab.TABLE_NAME AS MyTable

FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES tab
JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS Tab_con ON tab.TABLE_NAME = tab_con.TABLE_NAME
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
    AND tab.TABLE_NAME != 'sysdiagrams'
ORDER BY tab.TABLE_NAME ASC,
CASE WHEN Tab_con.Constraint_Type = 'PRIMARY KEY' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC;
```